# regarding the meaning of "#REF!" in reading a csv file

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, csv

I once read a line of code which is to read a csv file into pandas dataframe.

```
test = pd.read_csv(data_path,thousands=',').replace("#REF!", np.nan)
```

What does the `"#REF!"` mean? Does that correspond to any unique character?

Comment: That has nothing to do with Pandas.  That is an artifact of whatever produced the csv.  The author of that line of code was just trying to handle that value.  I believe that's an excel error.

Comment: Also, there is a likely better way to handle that.  `pd.read_csv(data_path, thousands=',', na_values='#REF!'))`  That should replace those values prior to creating the dataframe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That error comes from an Excel file. According to Microsoft docs: "The #REF! error shows when a formula refers to a cell that's not valid . This happens most often when cells that were referenced by formulas get deleted, or pasted over."